# Fixing gaps in line network with pgRouting/PostGIS

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I have a line network that I want to fix the gaps on (connect the edges).  I have tried the following:

```
SELECT pgr_nodeNetwork('migration.streams', 0.0001, 'id', 'geom'); -- fix gaps and dead ends?
```

then

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology(                                                                      
    'migration.streams_noded',
    0.00001,                                                                                    
    id := 'id',
    the_geom := 'geom',
    clean := 'true'
);
```

... but nothing changed.

I have also tried QGIS v.clean and set the snap tool threshold to 100m and the v.in.ogr snap tolerance to 100 and still nothing was fixed.

I want a solution in PostGIS/pgRouting, since I will be running into this type of problem often with the data set that I am using with a pgRouting query I have created using pgr_withPointsCost.

Example of gaps between lines -- 75m and 37 m, respectively:
[image: gaps between lines]

Comment: Have look at this.  It uses postgis topology instead of pgr, but it does work for fixing gaps.  You could process your data using this method, then load it into pgr.  https://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/use-postgis-topologies-to-clean-up-road-networks.html

Comment: You could also experiment with decreasing your tolerance when you create the pgr topology.  0.00001 is very approximately less than 5m https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Comment: Noding the network will add vertices where lines intersect.  It won't help close gaps, but it can help with dead ends and connectivity.

Comment: I don't want to be *that* guy, but: in the realm of computational geometry and algorithmic, a network without topology is quite literally nothing more than a bunch of random lines - and trying to de-randomize these is quite literally nothing more than a waste of time; even if you were spending *another day* on researching alternative data sources - that provide you with coherently referenced network topology - *it is 100% worth it*!